# Bound/inequality for Hankel function

Tags: inequality, bessel-functions

Suppose $H^{(1)}_p(z)$ is the Hankel function of the first kind with argument $z$ and order $p$. I found the inequality below in the paper "Multi-level fast multipole solution of the scattering problem" by S. Amini and A.T.J. Profit.
$$
\text{For } 1 \leq p \leq z, \,\, \vert H^{(1)}_p(z) \vert \leq 1.
$$

The paper did not point any reference to it, and I could not find any textbooks or literatures stating this. This inequality seems to be true in numerical experiments. Does anyone have any idea on how to prove this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Some thoughts:
Recall that
$$|H_1(z;p)|^2=|J(z;p)|^2+|Y(z;p)|^2$$
Which for $z,p\in\Bbb{R}$, as it seems in your case, is simply
$$|H_1(z;p)|^2=J(z;p)^2+Y(z;p)^2$$
There is the remarkable [Nicholson's integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9) for $-\pi/2<\arg z<\pi/2$:
$$J(z;p)^2+Y(z;p)^2=\frac{8}{\pi^2}\int_0^\infty\cosh(2\nu t)K_0(2z\sinh t)\mathrm dt$$
If you can prove that the integral is $\leq \pi^2/8$ you are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is motivating! Following this I prove that when $z = p$, then the integrand is decreasing w.r.t $z$. Then setting $z=p=\frac{1}{2}$ we could calculate the integral to be $\frac{\pi}{4}$. It is little bit cruder than expected, but enough for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $1\leq p \leq z$. By [Nicholson’s Integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E30)
,
$$
\left| {H_p^{(1)} (z)} \right|^2  = J_p^2 (z) + Y_p^2 (z) = \frac{8}{{\pi ^2 }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\cosh (2pt)K_0 (2z\sinh t)\mathrm{d}t} .
$$
Differentiation with respect to $p$ shows that the modulus square is monotonically increasing with respect to $p$. Consequently, $| H_p^{(1)} (z)| \leq | H_z^{(1)} (z)| $ whenever $1\leq p \leq z$. By a results of [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S021953051450033X),
$$
\left| {H_z^{(1)} (z)} \right| \!\le\! \frac{2}{{3\pi }}\frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2}\left( {6^{1/3} \frac{{\Gamma (1/3)}}{{z^{1/3} }} + \frac{3}{{10}}\frac{1}{z}} \right) \!\le\! \frac{2}{{3\pi }}\frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2}\left( {6^{1/3} \Gamma \!\left( {\frac{1}{3}} \right) + \frac{3}{{10}}} \right) \!=0.9497\ldots\!<1,
$$
provided $z\geq 1$.